# Does ASP.NET Core Data Protection call IXmlDecryptor.Decrypt on every request?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

We're using the [Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Blobs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Blobs/) and [Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Keys](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Keys/) packages for Data Protection, and our app seems to be making a LOT of requests to Azure KeyVault. I've tried spelunking through the ASP.NET Core code but it's difficult to follow.

Does the Data Protection feature make a call to `IXmlDecryptor.Decrypt` *every* time a Key is used (e.g. every time a cookie is deserialized) or is the decrypted key cached somewhere? Because the [AzureKeyVaultXmlDecryptor](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/extensions/Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Keys/src/AzureKeyVaultXmlDecryptor.cs) implementation makes a request to KeyVault every time it's called, which could incur a lot of costs if it's happening on every single request.